# Total Collapse in Understanding a Pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium

[image]

In the following system, the tension T is equal in magnitude to the weight W.

But how can I set this up in a system of equations?

This is my problem:

$\Sigma F=0=\left( \begin{array}{c}
0\\
-W\\
\end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}
-T\cos(a)\\
-T\sin(a)\\
\end{array} \right) \implies T=\frac{-W}{\sin(a)}$, which is obviously wrong.

Where is the flaw in my reasoning here? I have been trying for a while now to understand it, because I am embarrassed to post it here, but now I just want to know how my logic fails me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you error is that you applied the equations for a force in a system that is not isolated (the pulley makes a force as it is attached to the wall, same with the rope at the left). You can ignone the pulley if you analyze the individual parts separately.
For the mass:  $T-W=0$ so $T=W$

Comment: Thank you, Bruce. Could I bother you further by asking you to provide me with an example of an isolated system, just for comparison. I am not sure I entirely understood it, but just knowing that there is a reason satisfies me much more.

Comment: An isolated system is a system where you can identify all external forces acting upon it. Most systems are not isolated, rather what you do is to chose isolated parts where you know all the forces and thus can write an equation.